# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

What is wrong with declaration of the CellType? This is an implementation of linked list. listHead is a new empty linked list. Due to the usage listHead in other section of the code i tried to declare it as global variable.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct CellType* Position;
typedef int ElementType;
struct CellType{
    ElementType value;
    Position next;
};

class List{
public:
    CellType* listHead;
    void makeNull();    //Create a new list
    void insertList(ElementType x, Position p); //Insert element to the list
    void deleteList(Position p);    //delete an element at position p
    Position first();   //get Position of first
    Position end();     //get Position of end
    Position next(Position p);  //get position of next
    void printList();   //print list
};

void List::makeNull(){
    listHead = new CellType;
    listHead -> next = NULL;
}

void List::insertList(ElementType x, Position p){
    Position temp;
    temp = p -> next;
    p->next = new CellType;
    p->value = x;
    p->next->next = temp;
}

void List::deleteList(Position p){
    p->next = p->next->next;
}

Position List::first(){
    return (listHead);
}

Position List::end(){
    Position p;
    p = listHead;
    while(p->next != NULL){
        p = p->next;
    }
    return(p);
}

Position List::next(Position p){
    return(p->next);
}
```

Comment: Is this the whole program giving you the error? where is `int main()`

Comment: There's no global `listHead` in the above code (which sounds like a really terrible idea anyway). Also the question title appears to bear no relation to the content of the question.

Comment: I used the error code from terminal as heading. And the code here pasted is portion of the whole program. I tried to implement the linked list. The method is from IIT Madras lecture.

Comment: I learnt implementation of abstract data type does not bother about the internal technique, then why required a global declaration. Only class methods use this listHead abstract type.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the os version updates and version of g++. I am using MacOS 10.15.5.

compiled again with g++ then linked successfully.